# Julia - how to update WinRPM in julia version 0.6.4

Tags: julia, cobra

I'm new to Julia and I want to use COBRA Package.
For adding COBRA I use command :

```
Pkg.add("COBRA")
```

But when running, I get these errors:

> INFO: Building WinRPM

> WARNING: skipping repodata/repomd.xml, not in cache -- call WinRPM.update() to download

> WARNING: skipping repodata/repomd.xml, not in cache -- call WinRPM.update() to download

> INFO: Downloading https://cache.julialang.org/http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml

> WARNING: Unknown download failure, error code: 2148270086

> WARNING: Retry 1/5 downloading: https://cache.julialang.org/http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml

until:

> WARNING: Unknown download failure, error code: 2148270086

> WARNING: Retry 5/5 downloading: https://cache.julialang.org/http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml

> WARNING: received error 0 while downloading
> https://cache.julialang.org/http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml

After these errors, I have checked the link and I've found out the source is not there, anymore.
So then I ran this command as said above:

```
WinRPM.update()
```

But it has thrown this error:

> ERROR: UndefVarError: WinRPM not defined

Please Help me to add COBRA to Julia. I'm using version 0.6.4 because Cobra does not work on the next versions.(Windows 10)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you've mentioned, is that the original sources [used by the package](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/WinRPM.jl/blob/master/sources.list) aren't valid URLs anymore. The proper way to solve this is to open a pull request with the package to change the URLs (which I've now done [here](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/WinRPM.jl/pull/181) ). As a stopgap measure, here's a hacky way to work around this issue for now:

- Do a `Pkg.add("WinRPM")`. This might trigger the same warnings as above, ignore these.
- Next, `using WinRPM` to load the package we added
- Now, the source URLs are read from the `sources.list` file (linked above) into a global `WinRPM.sources` variable. We're going to edit this variable's contents to point to new working URLs. (**This is generally a terrible idea**, to directly poke into the internals of a module and change things.)

```
julia> WinRPM.sources[:] = replace.(WinRPM.sources, "Leap_42.3" => "Leap_15.3")
2-element Vector{String}:
 "https://cache.julialang.org/http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_15.3"
 "https://cache.julialang.org/http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win64/openSUSE_Leap_15.3"
```

- A `WinRPM.update()` should now work, and download things into a local cache.

---

> I'm using version 0.6.4 because Cobra does not work on the next versions.

I hope you mean Julia 1.6.4 here, or version 0.6.4 of something else in the stack. If you mean Julia version 0.6.4, you might face further problems down the road and find it hard to get support for such an old version.